# Is it a good idea to use the latest GCC for iOS development to get c++11 features?

Tags: ios, xcode, gcc

Can I use, for example, the MacPorts GCC 4.6 to get C++ lambda expressions and other modern features that Clang still lacks? I have read about compiling for OS/X and the limits on 32/64 bit binaries but not about iOS limits.

Will that cause any trouble compiling to iOS?

Comment: As you would agree, the problem with all of this is unknowns. If it is a professional effort, I won't suggest doing it. I use some TR1 features too, mostly std::tr1::shared_ptr which is there with XCode 4.2. I am not sure lambda sugar is so good that one would want to try a new compiler.

Comment: If you want to use c++ lambdas in your own iOS code, I would suggest you use Grand Central Dispatch blocks that will provide you with similar functionalities. Of course this code will not be compatible anywhere outside iOS/Cocoa.

Comment: If you want to track the status of c++11 in clang, you can go to this page: http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

Answer (score 1):

It is true that Apple don't care much about GCC anymore (they are going the LLVM route).

However, the GCC developer community is quite professional, and do have members very concerned by making GCC run well on recent MacOSX Apple machines. So I believe they do care about having  a recent GCC (ie 4.6.2) work well on MacOSX.

So I would suggest you to build a recent GCC from its latest source.

I don't know anything about iOS, but I would believe that some GCC guys know well it.

Comment: This is really an old answer, but I looked at your profile and thought you could - maybe - help me. I don't think gcc 5.2 supports being cross built for iPad mini 3 for instance. Running `uname -a` on it throws `Darwin xxxx-iPad 14.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Wed Jun 24 00:50:15 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2784.30.7-30/RELEASE_ARM64_S5L8960X iPad4, arm64, J85mAP` but this arch is not supported by gcc. Is there a trick, or is it impossible ? What do you think ?

Comment: I am not sure, but I believe that [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) could be cross-compiled for iOS. download a recent version (e.g. [GCC 5.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/)) from it source code, compile it (outside of the source tree) and ask more on `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org`. BTW consider installing Linux, it is so fun...

Comment: Actually I am building it as a charm on mac OSX and various 64bits linux os'es (including trisquel 7), so that I think that I will follow your advice and ask how to do it on `gcc-help`. Btw, why do you believe it is feasible ?

Comment: Because GCC is configurable for a lot of vary host & target systems.

Comment: Oh, ok. Actually iPad Mini 3's arch target host triple appears no to be supported by gcc 5.2... But I will post there nevertheless, in case there is known trick. Thx anyway Basile.

Comment: (for sake of precision the triple returned by `./config.guess`on my iPad mini 3 is `arm64-apple-darwin14.0.0`.